# actionscript 3 - random object selection

Tags: actionscript-3, random, selection

So I want a unit to be able to randomly target a player unit or a players allies.
I have all ally ships stored in an array and the player is on the stage separately.

Here is the code for the bullet creation, with the irrelevant stuff removed.

```
private function createBullet(): void {
    var rand = allies[Math.floor(Math.random()*allies.length)]; 

        _endX = rand.x 
        _endY = rand.y 

    }
```

With the code above I can make them target random ally ships, but I also want it to include the player ship (_player) when randomly selecting a target, but I cant add the player to the ally array so Im not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply a random number by length of array, add plus one to length.
If generated index is equal to the allies length, this means that "rand" is _player.

```
var randomIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allies.length + 1));
var rand:*;
if (randomIndex == allies.length - 1)
    rand = _player;
else
    rand = allies[randomIndex];
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but using the method above I'm getting Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: I tested it a bit more and found  the enemies will only shoot  if there is an ally alive and they will only shoot at the player ship.

Comment: Try this: 
`var randomIndex:int = Math.round(Math.random() * allies.length);
var rand:*;
if (randomIndex == allies.length)
    rand = _player;
else
    rand = allies[randomIndex];`